# Aliasing using the same Alias twice

Tags: sql, group-by

I have run across a query where the developer is using the same alias twice in the query.

This was done several times in the Query- so I don't think it was a mistake.  Is there a reason to do this that I am not aware of or, is it just sloppy work?

```
(Select
  AppointmentID
  ,Division
  ,Hospital
  ,ApptDate
  ,KeptDate
From
     (Select
          s1.AppointmentID
          ,s1.Division
          ,s1.Hospital
          ,s1.Apptdate
          ,s1.KeptDate
          From S1
          Group By
          s1.AppontmentID
          ,s1.Division
          ,s1.Hospital
          ,s1.Apptdate
          ,s1.KeptDate) as S2
Group By
  AppointmentID
  ,Division
  ,Hospital
  ,ApptDate
  ,KeptDate) As S2
```

This is the code simplified down- there are many more fields but no aggregate in them as well as the fact that both Group Bys follow one after the other.  There is nothing in between them.

Thanks,

Comment: That was just a typo on my part when transferring the code.

Comment: I am not trying to create this code I am wondering why it was done.  If there is a good reason for it.

Comment: The alias used twice is the least of troubles in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use aggregation unless you have an aggregation function (`MIN/MAX/AVG` etc.)
2. Try not to use the same alias twice (it's confusing)
3. When the smallest granularity (`AppointmentID`) is in the aggregation, it makes it useless (is it unique?) if it is unique, this will return the same result as a simple `SELECT` statment

Comment: Yeah- figured it was sloppy coding.  Just wondering if there was something I was missing as to why this would be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you strip down the external query you will get the same result. So this is sloppy work in this form.
But is you removed something important to simplify the example it can be a cause. (for example joined extra tables.)

Comment: Figured it was sloppy, just wondering if there was something that I was missing as to why they would have done this.